# How to start Angular2 app under a sub forlder

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

By follow Angular2 example, I create my first app
under my project folder. I can run: "npm start" to make the application running
For example I can access the app from http://localhost:3000

I have a new requirement which I need to run the application under a context path, which mean I need to access the application through http://localhost:3000/myapp

The question is how to deploy or run Angular2 application in a sub folder path?
try to add  in the index.html file. However, it seems Angular cannot resolve the path to find the template URL and resource JS and TS files.

Can anyone help to make sure I can run the app under a context path "myapp"?

Answer (score 3):

Add *base* tag to `index.html`:

```
<base href="/myapp">
```

or in your bootstrap file (main.js)

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/myapp'}),
]);
```